# Launching Dota2 using create_subprocess_exec with arguments

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I'm trying to launch Dota2 on a Windows 10 box using python 3.7 with arguments specified that will auto launch a bot-game using asyncio.create_subprocess_exec(). The game currently launches, but it looks like the arguments are ignored as it does not launch the bot-game automatically, just the Dota2 application.

Doing something similar with the `subprocess` module and `Popen()` works just fine.

```
import asyncio
from sys import platform

args = [
    'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Steam\\steamapps\\common\\dota 2 beta\\game\\bin\\win64\\dota2.exe',
    '-con_logfile scripts/vscripts/bots/console.log',
    '-con_timestamp',
    '-console',
    '-dev',
    '-insecure',
    '-noip',
    '-nowatchdog',
    '+clientport 27006',
    '+dota_1v1_skip_strategy 1',
    '+dota_surrender_on_disconnect 0',
    '+host_timescale 1',
    '+hostname dotaservice',
    '+sv_cheats 1',
    '+sv_hibernate_when_empty 0',
    '+tv_delay 0',
    '+tv_enable 1',
    '+tv_title some_uuid',
    '+tv_autorecord 1',
    '+tv_transmitall 1',
    '-fill_with_bots',
    '+map',
    'start gamemode 6',
    '+sv_lan 1'
]

def main_func():
    if platform == "win32":
        asyncio.set_event_loop(asyncio.ProactorEventLoop())
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    tasks = offline_main()
    loop.run_until_complete(tasks)

async def offline_main():
    create = asyncio.create_subprocess_exec(args[0], ' '.join(args[1:]), stdin=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE, stdout=None, stderr=None)
    await create

#main_func()

def sub_func():
    import subprocess
    p = subprocess.Popen('"'+args[0]+'" '+' '.join(args[1:]), stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=None, stderr=None)

#sub_func()
```

If you uncomment `sub_func()` it works just fine. If you uncomment `main_func()` it launches Dota2 Application but does not start a bot-game. I realize there is minor differences in arguments passed, but if I use:

```
create = asyncio.create_subprocess_exec('"'+args[0]+'" '+' '.join(args[1:]), stdin=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE, stdout=None, stderr=None)
```

I get a `PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied` for some reason

Comment: You are not doing the same in these methods - are you sure the difference does not come from that? What happens if you use ``subprocess.Popen`` with a list of arguments instead of a string, as in ``p = subprocess.Popen(args)`` given the ``args`` used for ``offline_main``? Does the ``stdin`` pipe have any effect, e.g. expecting input?

Comment: If I launch the `subprocess.Popen(args)` as you suggested it still launches Dota2 application, but no longer auto-joins a bot game either. I expect the issue is in how the arguments are passed. Just can't figure out how to pass them in the same way using asyncio as I was doing in `Popen()` 

This works though:
`p = subprocess.Popen('"'+args[0]+'" '+' '.join(args[1:]))`

Comment: I updated the original post to make comparison between the two methods much easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it works if you separate all the arguments including the values you want to set them to.

Code below works:

```
import asyncio
from sys import platform

args = [
    'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Steam\\steamapps\\common\\dota 2 beta\\game\\bin\\win64\\dota2.exe',
    '-con_logfile', 'scripts/vscripts/bots/console.log',
    '-con_timestamp',
    '-console',
    '-dev',
    '-insecure',
    '-noip',
    '-nowatchdog',
    '+clientport', '27006',
    '+dota_1v1_skip_strategy', '1',
    '+dota_surrender_on_disconnect', '0',
    '+host_timescale', '1',
    '+hostname dotaservice',
    '+sv_cheats', '1',
    '+sv_hibernate_when_empty', '0',
    '+tv_delay', '0',
    '+tv_enable', '1',
    '+tv_title', 'some_uuid',
    '+tv_autorecord', '1',
    '+tv_transmitall', '1',
    '-fill_with_bots',
    '+map',
    'start', 'gamemode', '6',
    '+sv_lan', '1'
]

def main_func():
    if platform == "win32":
        asyncio.set_event_loop(asyncio.ProactorEventLoop())
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    tasks = offline_main()
    loop.run_until_complete(tasks)

async def offline_main():
    create = asyncio.create_subprocess_exec(*args, stdin=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE, stdout=None, stderr=None)
    await create

main_func()

def sub_func():
    import subprocess
    p = subprocess.Popen('"'+args[0]+'" '+' '.join(args[1:]), stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=None, stderr=None)

#sub_func()
```